# why is add record button creating a blank record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an add record button in my access 201 database. When I add a record it creates the record plus a blank record how do I fix this so a blank record is not created.

```
Private Sub Add_Record_Command18_Click() 

On Error GoTo Err_Add_Record_Command18_Click 
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec 

Exit_Add_Record_Command18_Click: 
    Exit Sub 

Err_Add_Record_Command18_Click: 
    MsgBox Err.Description 
    Resume Exit_Add_Record_Command18_Click 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Private Sub Add_Record_Command18_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Add_Record_Command18_Click


    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

Exit_Add_Record_Command18_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Add_Record_Command18_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Add_Record_Command18_Click
End Sub

Comment: I do not undstand what you added

Comment: I added the code you posted, it will help you to get an answer.